# Not working sample program from a java book

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am still learning, trying to run a code from a Bulgarian java book but it is not working. Can someone take a look?

```
public class BinaryTree {
    public static class BinaryTreeNode<T> {
        private T value;
        private boolean hasParent;
        private BinaryTreeNode<T> leftChild;
        private BinaryTreeNode<T> rightChild;

        /**
         * Constructs a binary tree node.
         *
         * @param value      - the value of the node.
         * @param leftChild  - the left child of the node.
         * @param rightChild - the right child of the node.
         */
        public BinaryTreeNode(T value,
                              BinaryTreeNode<T> leftChild,
                              BinaryTreeNode<T> rightChild) {
            if (value == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "Cannot insert null value!");
            }

            this.value = value;
            this.leftChild = leftChild;
            this.rightChild = rightChild;
        }

        /**
         * Constructs a binary tree node with no children.
         *
         * @param value - the value of the node.
         */
        public BinaryTreeNode(T value) {
            this(value, null, null);
        }

        public T getValue() {
            return this.value;
        }

        public void setValue(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public BinaryTreeNode<T> getLeftChild() {
            return this.leftChild;
        }

        public void setLeftChild(BinaryTreeNode<T> value) {
            if (value == null || value.hasParent) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }

            value.hasParent = true;
            this.leftChild = value;
        }

        public BinaryTreeNode<T> getRightChild() {
            return this.rightChild;
        }

        public void setRightChild(BinaryTreeNode<T> value) {
            if (value == null || value.hasParent) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }

            value.hasParent = true;
            this.rightChild = value;
        }
    }

    // The root of the tree
    private BinaryTreeNode<T> root;

    /**
     * Constructs the tree.
     * @param value - the value of the node.
     * @param children - the children of the node.
     */
    public BinaryTree(T value, BinaryTree<T> leftChild,
                      BinaryTree<T> rightChild) {

        if (value == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        BinaryTreeNode<T> leftChildNode =
                leftChild != null ? leftChild.root : null;
        BinaryTreeNode<T> rightChildNode =
                rightChild != null ? rightChild.root : null;
        this.root = new BinaryTreeNode<T>(
                value, leftChildNode, rightChildNode);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs the tree.
     * @param value - the value of the node.
     */
    public BinaryTreeNode<T> getRoot() {
        return this.root;
    }

    /**
     * @return the left child of the root.
     */
    public BinaryTreeNode<T> getLeftChildNode() {
        if (this.root != null) {
            return this.root.getLeftChild();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Traverses binary tree in pre-order manner.
     * @param root - the binary tree to be traversed.
     */
    private void printPreOrder(BinaryTreeNode<T> root) {
        if (root == null) {
            return;
        }

        printPreOrder(root.getLeftChild());

        System.out.print(root.getValue() + " ");

        printPreOrder(root.getRightChild());
    }

    /**
     * Traverses and prints the binary
     * tree in pre-order manner.
     */
    public void printPreOrder() {
        printPreOrder(this.root);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Here I get below the "The root of the tree" line "Cannot resolve symbol "T"".

And the second part - the test:

```
public class BinaryTreeExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
// Create the binary tree from the sample.
        BinaryTree<Integer> binaryTree =
                new BinaryTree<Integer>(14,
                        new BinaryTree<Integer>(19,
                                new BinaryTree<Integer>(23),
                                new BinaryTree<Integer>(6,
                                        new BinaryTree<Integer>(10),
                                        new BinaryTree<Integer>(21))),
                        new BinaryTree<Integer>(15,
                                new BinaryTree<Integer>(3),
                                null));
// Traverse and print the tree in pre-order manner.
        binaryTree.printPreOrder();
    }
}
```

I get "BinaryTree does not have type parameters". This is from IntelliJ editor before compilation. When I try to run the program I also get a lot of errors mostly the same. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Quick look only, but shouldn't `BinaryTree` be declared generic as well?

Comment: hi, can you please share the name of the book??

Comment: *"BinaryTree does not have type parameters"* - What is unclear about that? That class is not generic. Is it generic in the book?

Answer (score 0):

Here `BinaryTree<Integer> binaryTree` you use generic, but when you declare `BinaryTree`(`public class BinaryTree {`), you didn't use generic. So you have to add generic to declaration of `BinaryTree` or remove generic from creation `BinaryTree` object.

Answer (score 0):

To correct your error, you should replace all usages of BinaryTree Integer with BinaryTree, but it would make more sense to declare BinaryTree as generic, BinaryTree. Your code declared a node of tree as generic, but unless you want different type nodes within same tree, you should declare tree as generic and make its nodes follow this type.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code:

```
public class BinaryTree<T> {
    public static class BinaryTreeNode<T>
    {
        // Contains the value of the node
        private T value;
        // Shows whether the current node has parent
        private boolean hasParent;
        // Contains the left child of the node
        private BinaryTreeNode<T> leftChild;
        // Contains the right child of the node
        private BinaryTreeNode<T> rightChild;

        /**
         * Constructs a binary tree node.
         * @param value - the value of the node.
         * @param leftChild - the left child of the node.
         * @param rightChild - the right child of the node.
         */
        public BinaryTreeNode(T value,
                              BinaryTreeNode<T> leftChild,
                              BinaryTreeNode<T> rightChild)
        {
            if (value == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "Cannot insert null value!");
            }
            this.value = value;
            this.leftChild = leftChild;
            this.rightChild = rightChild;
        }
        public BinaryTreeNode(T value)
        {
            this(value, null, null);
        }

        /**
         * @return the value of the node.
         */
        public T getValue() {
            return this.value;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the value of the node.
         * @param value - the value to be set.
         */
        public void setValue(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        /**
         * @return the left child or null if it does not exists.
         */
        public BinaryTreeNode<T> getLeftChild() {
            return this.leftChild;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the left child.
         * @param value - the new left child to be set.
         */
        public void setLeftChild(BinaryTreeNode<T> value) {
            if (value == null || value.hasParent) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            value.hasParent = true;
            this.leftChild = value;
        }

        /**
         * @return the right child or null if it does not exists.
         */
        public BinaryTreeNode<T> getRightChild() {
            return this.rightChild;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the right child.
         * @param value - the new right child to be set.
         */
        public void setRightChild(BinaryTreeNode<T> value) {
            if (value == null || value.hasParent) {throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            value.hasParent = true;
            this.rightChild = value;
        }
    }

    // The root of the tree
    private BinaryTreeNode<T> root;

    /**
     * Constructs the tree.
     * @param value - the value of the node.
     * @param children - the children of the node.
     */
    public BinaryTree(T value, BinaryTree<T> leftChild,
                      BinaryTree<T> rightChild) {
        if (value == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        BinaryTreeNode<T> leftChildNode =
                leftChild != null ? leftChild.root : null;
        BinaryTreeNode<T> rightChildNode =
                rightChild != null ? rightChild.root : null;
        this.root = new BinaryTreeNode<T>(
                value, leftChildNode, rightChildNode);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs the tree.
     * @param value - the value of the node.
     */
    public BinaryTree(T value) {
        this(value, null, null);
    }
    /**
     * @return the root of the tree.
     */
    public BinaryTreeNode<T> getRoot()
    {
        return this.root;
    }

/**
 * @return the left child of the root.
 * */
public BinaryTreeNode<T> getLeftChildNode()
{
    if (this.root != null)
    {
        return this.root.getLeftChild();
    }
    return null;
}
    /**
     * @return the right child of the root.
     */
    public BinaryTreeNode<T> getRightChildNode()
    {
        if (this.root != null)
        {
            return this.root.getRightChild();
        }
        return null;
    }
    /**
     * Traverses binary tree in pre-order manner.
     * @param root - the binary tree to be traversed.
     */
    private void printPreOrder(BinaryTreeNode<T> root) {
        if (root == null) {
            return;
        }

// 1. Visit the left child.
        printPreOrder(root.getLeftChild());
// 2. Visit the root of this subtree.
        System.out.print(root.getValue() + " ");
// 3. Visit the right child.
        printPreOrder(root.getRightChild());
    }

    /**
     * Traverses and prints the binary
     * tree in pre-order manner.
     */
    public void printPreOrder() {
        printPreOrder(this.root);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```